# Are Java classes a good replacement for an SQL relational database?

Tags: java, sql, relational-database

The reason I am asking this is because it seems (for me) a lot easier to set-up a file management system in Java than to set up a complicated relational database in SQL. What would having an SQL relational database benefit me over the following example:

Example: a Products file that allows variable pricing for the same product

in Java:

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
    public static int productCount = 0;
    private final int productID;
    private final long productRegisterDate;
    private String productDescription;
    private List<ProductPrice> productPrices;
    Product (String desc) {
        productID = ++productCount;
        productRegisterDate = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        productDescription = desc;
        productPrices = new ArrayList<ProductPrice>();
    }
    public Product addPrice(double price, String priceDesc) {
        productPrices.add(new ProductPrice(price, priceDesc);
        return this;
    }
    public void updateProduct(String desc, ArrayList<ProductPrice> prices) {
        productDescription = desc;
        productPrices = prices;
    }
    public int getID() return productID;
    public long getDateRegistered() return productRegisterDate;
    public String getDescription() return productDescription;
    public ArrayList<ProductPrice> getPrices() return productPrices;
}
public class ProductPrice implements Serializable {
    private double price;
    private String priceDescription;
    ProductPrice(double price, String priceDesc) {
        this.price = price;
        priceDescription = priceDesc;
    }
}
```

inserting products:

```
...
List<Product> myProducts = new ArrayList<Product>();
myProducts.add(new Product("product a")
    .addPrice(1.99,"250g pack")
    .addPrice(2.99,"500g pack");
```

find Product objects:

```
...
public Product findProductById(int pid) {
    for (Product p:myProducts)
        if (p.getID() == pid) return p;
    return null;
}
public List<Product> searchProducts(String searchTerm, int limit) {
    List<Product> results = new ArrayList<Product>();
    int count = 0;
    for (Product p:myProducts) {
        if (p.getDescription().indexOf(searchTerm)>-1) {
            results.add(p);
            count++;
            if (count >= limit) break;
        }
    return results;
}
```

query product info with object:

```
...
String productDescription = p.getDescription();
```

update product info without object:

```
public boolean updateProductByID(int pid, String desc, ArrayList<ProductPrice> prices) {
    Product p = null;
    try {
        p = findProductById(pid);
        p.updateProduct(desc, prices);
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

save/load data:

```
...
private final String SAVE_PATH = "C:/";
private final String PRODUCTS_FILE = "Products.dat";
public static boolean saveProducts(ArrayList<Product> myProducts) {
    ObjectOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(SAVE_PATH+PRODUCTS_FILE));
        out.writeObject(myProducts);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
public static boolean loadProducts(ArrayList<Product> myProducts) {
    ObjectInputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(SAVE_PATH+PRODUCTS_FILE));
        myProducts = (ArrayList<Product>) in.readObject();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        return false;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e2) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please advise me, I want to know all of the details.
Bear in mind I already have a Java application with class objects (i.e. Products, Orders, etc) and I am wondering if I should use a database to serve and store the data rather than the local file system.

Comment: So, your file based option can handle concurrency and ACID as well as a database? They can handle the ad-hock queries a RDBMS can?

Comment: And it can be accessed by arbitrary DB/reporting tools?

Comment: if you're going to have a `find product by id` method, you should probably have an index on that. In Java, I'd recommend a hashmap if you were going to do it yourself.

Comment: What happens to the serialized data when you change your objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reinvent anything you want to, if you really want to.

Pros:

- You learn a lot.
- You have complete control over the system.

Cons:

- You have complete control over the system.
- You lose the experience of those who make a living making whatever system you reinvent.
- You have to fix all bugs you find yourself.
- You have to test it yourself (millions of people use RDBMS already, for example).
- When you find a problem you won't know if it's your database system, or the system that uses it.

So the question is, how much time are you willing to spend creating this?

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLLite + Hibernate, it will simplify your code a lot. I think your current approach will give you a perspective to common db problems: concurrency, consistency, maintaining relations..etc etc. If you don't plan on using any of those, you can implement your solution in pure Java. However, if you think you can benefit from what i said above, it is better to use a db for your needs. But if you are doing it for educational purposes as I believe you are, then stick to your approach.

Answer (score 0):

As Oded very well mentioned, concurrency, ACID and ad-hock queries are a few reasons why you would want a DB. I would add sorting, unique constraints, relations, replication, and many many other tools that DB engines provide you with.

If you like working with objects, you could start using hibernate, over a very simple to setup DB like SQLLite. When your application grows, you could pretty easily move on from SQLLite to MySQL, PostgreSQL or Oracle.